# How to disable button when clicked button to action window location and enable it again after window location finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

there's action button click, if button click on then call api to return file (export to excel) use window.location, i need to disable it in process export and loading window location, after that i need to enable it again after window location finished.
there's way to enable it again if process successfully?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+disable+button+while+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: If it is a button, disable it in the click event handler. If it is a submit button in a form, disable it in the submit event handler

Comment: If you open a new window/tab to download, then the original tab doesn't know when its finished.  If you use `location.href =` to download the file then you'll have navigated away from your page (though it *looks like* you're still on the page, you're not) - and the JS on your page will have been unloaded.

Comment: yeah but i need to enable it again after process export finished @mplungjan

Comment: thankyou, then i can't to enable it with trigger from location.href loaded ya? @freedomn-m